Type narrowing using factory function for union type, discriminators and Partial<T>
I need to implement a factory function that creates an instance of a subtype - the factory function accepts the type discriminator plus a subset of properties that should be populated via Partial<T>.
This is a minimal code example:
type TypeA = {
  discriminator: 'A';
  aProp: string;
};

type TypeB = {
  discriminator: 'B';
  bProp: string;
};

type TypeX = TypeA | TypeB; // either of the two types

type TypeDiscriminator = TypeX['discriminator']; // "A" | "B"

function createInstance(discriminator: TypeDiscriminator, partial: Partial<TypeX>) {
  switch (discriminator) {
    case 'A':
      return { ...partial, discriminator: 'A' } as TypeA;
    case 'B':
      return { ...partial, discriminator: 'B' } as TypeB;
    default:
      throw Error();
  }
}

// Question: This should infer type to 'TypeA' (but it is TypeA | TypeB instead)
export const a = createInstance('A', { aProp: 'foobar' });

// this works, but is actually invalid (aProp does not exist on TypeB and should be caught as error)
export const b = createInstance('B', { aProp: 'foobar' }) as TypeB;

How would this be properly be implemented, without alterting the parameter list of createInstance?

This works:
function createInstance<D extends TypeDiscriminator>(
  discriminator: D,
  partial: Partial<Extract<TypeX, { discriminator: D }>>
) {}

It picks the right type based on the discriminator given.

That works! Note: The typecasts as TypeA, as TypeB inside the return statement of the switch must be removed for this to work (which is even better!).

Great! Glad I could help.

But how to specify the return type? If I pass in the discriminator, the return type should not be the union, but the concrete type that matches that discriminator

You can do the same thing on the return: Extract<TypeX, { discriminator: D }>.
But then you have to assert the returns inside the switch statement.
